# Where is robots.txt exist in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, robots.txt, yoast

I created a web application using wordpress. When I search name in google it is showing

> A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt

I enter url/robots.txt.It display

```
User-agent: *

Disallow: /#/register
Disallow: /#/login 
Sitemap: http://www./sitemap.xml
```

I want to change this text file. Is this possible.

Comment: what SEO plugin you are using?

Comment: yoast seo plugin

Answer (score 2):

If you site is hosted in root directory then robots.txt are stored in

```
public_html/robots.txt
```

Or as you can go to *Tools - Yoast SEO* page and edit it form there.

Please read this official doc form more details. [How to edit robots.txt through Yoast SEO?](https://kb.yoast.com/kb/how-to-edit-robots-txt-through-yoast-seo/)

Hope this helps!